# What is the correct way to handle edits where a user highlighted "names"

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, syntax-highlighting

So I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439355/connecting-smartgit-and-bitbucket-repository-to-android-studio) ([edit approval](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10666773)) and I noticed that it had been edited in such a way that many words (apparently names/key-words) became highlighted.

Like:

- Android
- Android Studio
- SmartGit
- VCS
- BitBucket
- Android Project

I also tend to highlight words but only when they're some kind of function or class. This person seems to have highlighted every single name in the post, I think that's no improvement whatsoever.

Anyway, I decided to rollback the edit. But when I took a look at the list of people who approved the edit I started to doubt, hence this question *(I searched for a similar question but could not find it)*.

**Is highlighting names (not functions or class names) considered an improvement?**

Comment: @approxiblue thanks, it doesn't exactly answer my question, it assumes random highlighting is bad thing. But I guess that's the same for highlighting names of some sort?

Comment: @approxiblue:  No, I'm not convinced that's a better dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Know what else was missed?

- i've
- Help pls :)

The edit was ***definitely*** too minor.  There wasn't any improvement by adding backticks to anything.

It's annoying, but it should have been rejected and revised to be more correct instead of being just edited.

If you notice a pattern of this, flag the edit and explain to a moderator what's going on.  One or two occurrences are enough that you could @message the editor (their name won't appear in autocomplete it will reach them) and let them know that their suggestion was too minor.